# floating point system formula

Tags: numerical-methods, data-analysis

My textbook defines the floating point number system as the numbers given by $$x=(-1)^s\cdot \beta^{-k}\sum_{j=0}^{N-2}a_j\beta^j$$
where $N$ is the number of memory positions for a number $x\in\mathbb R$ with digits $a_j$ and base $\beta$. Also, $s=0$ whenever $x>0$ and $s=1$ otherwise (this I understand).

I do not understand how this formula is developed at all. can anyone help?

Comment: Just asking: Can you carefully write down (for yourself) what the expressions $3.1416$ or $-2.71828$ mean as decimal numbers?

Comment: Are you familiar with how *integers* are represented in binary?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That helped, but I got a very similar formula. The formula I got is $(-1)^s\cdot \beta^{-m}\sum_{i=-m}^{n} x_i\beta^{m+i}$

Comment: The details depend on notation. The formula in your comment may not match your textbook, but it's certainly on the right track, though it appears to have $m$ in too many places. It may help to set $m = 2$ (say) and to write out exactly what your formula expresses. <> Once that works out, the next question is, what do $N$ and $k$ denote in the book's formula, and what do $m$ and $n$ denote in your formula? (Do feel free to answer your own question when you get the details worked out, by the way!)